# How many E1 tributaries can be carried in one STM-4?

Tags: fiber

This is how I did it

Bit rate of **E1** is **2.048 Mbps** and bit rate of **STM-4** is **622.08 Mbs**
I divided the bit rate of **STM-4** by the bit rate of **E1** and got the answer as **303**.
Is this correct? Or do I have to consider about the payload of STM-4?

Comment: This doesn't consider framing and other signaling overhead. (the correct answer appears to be 256. 7680 / 30 = 256)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**STM-4 = 252 x E1**

The simplest way is to go step-by-step through hierarchy:
STM-1 carries up to 63 E1
STM-4 carries up to 4 STM-1
(if you need to go further STM-16=4*STM-4 and so on)

So STM-4 = 4 * 63 * E1 = 252 * E1